java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys
I was trying to build a project  using JWT. I have installed the io.jsonwebtoken package with version 0.11.5 in order to do that.
My pom.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.atguigu</groupId>
        <artifactId>lease</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>common</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--mybatis-plus-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-plus-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--mysql驱动-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.minio</groupId>
            <artifactId>minio</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--spring-web-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.whvcse</groupId>
            <artifactId>easy-captcha</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aliyun</groupId>
            <artifactId>dysmsapi20170525</artifactId>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

</project>

JwtUtil.Java
package com.atguigu.lease.common.utils;




import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.util.Date;

public class JwtUtil {

    private static long tokenExpiration = 60 * 60 * 1000L;
    private static SecretKey tokenSignKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor("M0PKKI6pYGVWWfDZw90a0lTpGYX1d4AQ".getBytes());

    public static String createToken(Long userId, String username) {
        String token = Jwts.builder().
                setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + tokenExpiration)).
                setSubject("LOGIN_USER").
                claim("userId", userId).
                claim("username", username).
                signWith(tokenSignKey,SignatureAlgorithm.HS256).
                compact();
        return token;
    }



}

While I'm trying to import "io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys" I'm getting this error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys.
I  am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this
I' ve looked around and apparently I've got the choice between these libraries
enter image description here

If you can see the JAR files in the external libraries but are still encountering compilation issues, try right-clicking on the required JAR(s) (e.g., io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.12.0) in the dependencies folder and select "Download Sources. Repeat for other dependencies too. This might resolve the compilation problem.
